# Images Fail to Display When Exported to WORD from SSRS

Tags: image, ms-word, ssrs-2008, export

When I set the database image Sizing property to 'Fit Proportional' and export the document to WORD some of the database images fail to render.  If on the other hand the image sizing property is 'Fit to Size' then all the images always render when exported to WORD.  I eliminated all report elements except the image in the body but the results are the same.

Additional Info:  The image is not nested in a rectangle or table.  The DB images originated as jpegs and are stored as VARCHAR(max).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is more of a Word problem than SSRS. When you say "some" images fail to render when set to "Fit Proportional" that makes me think that the image is too large to fit on the page therefore not displaying.

I would guess the images that don't go beyond the margins of the page are the ones that display properly.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input but the images that fail to display have the same dimensions (480x480) as the images that correctly display.  When the problematic images render in WORD they have the correct height but the width is set to .01 so the images look like vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I was trying to export to Word and some images were not showing while others were. I found this thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/211c2ee1-30a7-4c42-88bd-88333a6fe988/missing-images-in-headerfooter-when-exporting-to-word-in-ssrs-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices

Someone suggesting reducing the image size before importing it into SSRS. That worked for me, so it might help you.

Comment: You submitted the same answer twice. If you think the two questions can be answered by the same answer, consider flagging as duplicate when you have enough reputation.